# "Belated happy birthday" or "happy belated birthday"?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, word-order, past-participles

What's the correct sentence?

> - Belated happy birthday!
> - Happy belated birthday!

Comment: -1 It depends on what has been "belated", the greetings or the  birthday. Unless someone is celebrating birthday past the actual date of their birth, there would be no such thing as a "belated birthday".

Comment: Both are common, but "happy belated birthday" is far more common. Sources: Google Ngram Viewer, Google Search.

Comment: @MετάEd I don't know why it's more common because it doesn't make any sense. What are you expressing? Happy *late* Birthday? Surely birthdays can't be late, but the birthday greeting can be.

Comment: That is always the dilemma of the prescriptivist. It is the common expression *because it is*.

Comment: @MετάEd Hmm. Just did a google Ngram on that and it shows the reverse of what you're saying. Belated Happy Birthday is a lot more popular - http://tinyurl.com/becwmpv

Comment: Google Ngram Viewer is case sensitive. When you capitalize the first word of each sentence, "Belated happy birthday" goes away completely. Or, using Google Search (which is case insensitive), do a quoted search and check the estimated number of occurrences of each phrase.

Comment: Sorry @spiceyokooko, not in the US. Here you can easily buy greeting cards stating "Happy Belated Birthday", but you will not find one saying "Belated Happy Birthday"

Comment: @KristinaLopez Well thank goodness for British English is all I can say :-)

Comment: @spiceyokooko: You claim that "birthdays can't be late", but one could argue that birthdays can't be happy, either. (A person celebrating their birthday can be happy, but the date itself isn't happy). "Happy birthday," then, is just a concise well-wishing greeting, it means, "I hope your birthday is a happy day for you." In a similar way, "Happy belated birthday" simply means "I know this greeting is late, but I hope you had a happy birthday." I wouldn't read too much into the ordering of the words.

Comment: @J.R. that a day on which people are, or should be, happy, is itself *happy* is well-attested from Shakespeare to the hymn well-known in its 1960s Gospel version. It's quite reasonable for people to reason that one is preferable over the other, even if both are found.

Comment: @Jon: My response was more about spicey's assertion in the third comment down, not because I had a problem with the greeting. By the way, happy belated new year to you. 8^)

Comment: I am of the opinion that 'belated happy birthday greetings/wishes' is the most grammatical and sensible.

Comment: Those saying that a birthday can't be belated must not know any women over about 25. Women very often delay celebrating their 30th birthday until they're about 40. :)

Comment: I have just conducted a thoroughly scientific study of birthday cards, consisting of internet image searches on "happy belated birthday" and "belated happy birthday" and counting images that looked like cards. Before I got bored counting, I found 20 "Happy Belated Birthday", 4 "Belated Happy Birthday", and 18 other ("Sorry I missed your Birthday", etc.) So despite the fact that I think "Belated Happy Birthday" makes a lot more sense, apparently card manufacturers disagree.

Comment: I always say Belated Happy Birthday ("Late" Happy Birthday) instead of Happy Belated Birthday (Happy "Late" Birthday.) To me, the latter just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Many people are trying to analyze the meaning of the phrase from its constituent words. But "Happy Belated Birthday" is idiomatic. And "Happy Birthday" is also idiomatic and it doesn't necessarily mean that the day is happy. It might mean something like "I care for you and celebrate that you have survived/thrived for another year".

Answer (score 20):

Personally, I've used both versions. Nevertheless:

- *Belated birthday* is nonsense, since the anniversary **is** the anniversary, and cannot be postponed even if the celebrations are.
- *Belated happy birthday*, strictly, is also nonsense because the birthday has already gone and may or may not have been happy.

Therefore I would suggest something along the lines of:

- *Belated birthday wishes* (as suggested in another answer)
- *Hope you had a Happy Birthday. Sorry I missed it / Sorry I'm late.*

Comment: @user300672 I agree with you that 'belated H/happy B/birthday' is idiomatic and an accepted paraphrase of 'This is a belated card / wish signalling that I hoped that you would have a good day on your birthday'. See MetaEd's findings above. However, the answerer here seems not to like this analysis, and changing his answer to fit with your views is not permissible. It might even be illegal.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for protecting the gist of my original answer! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Well *belated* means *behind date* or *late*.

From Oxford English Dictionary:

> belated, adj.
>
> 1. Detained beyond the usual time, coming or staying too late; out of date, behind date.

So, if you're wishing someone a *Happy Birthday* which is late, you would use:

> Belated *Happy Birthday*

Comment: Or, ["Happy belated birthday"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=belated+happy+birthday%2Chappy+belated+birthday%2CHappy+belated+birthday%2C+Belated+happy+birthday&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=). That's just what people [say sometimes](http://www.google.com/search?q="Happy%20belated%20birthday"&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1976,cd_max:2006&lr=lang_en).

Comment: J.R. Not in the UK or British English - it simply isn't used, in fact I've never heard of it being used like that before. It's the same for other greetings such as Happy Easter, Happy Christmas, if they're late, it's *belated* Happy Easter, not Happy belated Easter. But given this site tends to be dominated by Americans, I can see why *they* would prefer the unheard of version.

Comment: I don't see any point in arguing about which is right and which is wrong, but I always find it interesting to learn about a new across-the-pond difference in usage.

Comment: @J.R. I'm not really arguing about which is right or which is wrong - I merely pointed out the one I'm most familiar with. However, I have noticed that the American dominance on this site seems to ensure that *American English* prevails whilst happily ignoring the fact that British English also exists. The whole world does not start and end at the West and East coast of America - something most Americans would do well to understand.

Comment: Methinks you're mischaracterizing the community. Many of our more prominant members (Barrie England, FumbleFingers, Colin Fine, Andrew Leach, to name a few) hail from somewhere other than the USA. Many of our members who do reside in the U.S. hardly seem like xenophobes or ignorant of English usage outside of North America (Peter Shor, JS Bangs and Martha come to mind). Sure, there are plenty of Americans who wonder what _colours_ are, but I don't run across many of them on ELU. Maybe I'm misreading you, but you seem to be more bitter than this situation calls for.

Comment: @spiceyokooko Oh please, I bend over backwards to accommodate BrE, The fact is we don't go round saying Belated Happy Birthday, verbally to people, generally speaking. In any event, it is the wishing of happy birthday that is belated: ergo, happy belated birthday is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

"Belated", of course, refers to something that has been delayed. 
From Merriam-Webster:

> be·lat·ed adjective \bi-ˈlā-təd, bē-\
>   1: delayed beyond the usual time 
>   2: existing or appearing past the normal or proper time

So, to wish someone after their actual birthday, the best phrase in my opinion would be "Belated birthday wishes", because it's just your wishes that got delayed.

Among the two options yo've given, "Belated Happy Birthday" is more common in my part of the world than the other.

Answer (score 1):

The perception that there is something paradoxical or nonsensical about *belated happy birthday* and its variants is due to taking *happy birthday* itself at face value, that is, as an expression of a wish that the addressee's birthday (one particular day) be happy. However, when people say *happy birthday*, their wishes are usually not specifically focused on that day. If they were, it would make much more sense to express such wishes in the morning, rather than the evening, when most of the day is already gone, but the latter is, in fact, far more common. The expression *happy birthday*, instead conveys vague wishes that the addressee's life generally go well, combined with the recognition of the birthday. If what is packed into *happy birthday* were made fully explicit, it would amount to something like: 'Noting that today is your birthday, and appreciating the significance of that fact, I wish you that your life go well in the future'.

There is nothing paradoxical about expressing such wishes with some delay. What is conveyed by a *belated happy birthday* message is something like: 'Noting that your birthday was a few days ago, and appreciating the significance of that fact, I wish you that your life go well in the future'.

Now, there may still be something syntactically puzzling about *belated happy birthday* in that *belated* in it seems to qualify *birthday* and it is unclear what that would mean (relative to what is the birthday delayed?). That puzzle can be resolved if we think of *happy birthday* analogously to *thank you*. It is generally accepted that the latter phrase can be used not only as an exclamation actually expressing thanks, but also as a noun phrase standing for something that expresses thanks. If somebody were to write 'Here is my belated thank you for . . .', we wouldn't have any problem understanding that *thank you* is used in the latter way, and that *belated* qualifies *thank you* as a whole. Similarly, when we receive a card saying *belated happy birthday*, we should think of *belated* as qualifying the whole of *happy birthday*, rather than just *birthday*.

Answer (score 0):

I would favour the first, because a wish for one to have a happy birthday is possible, but a belated birthday is not, though the second suggests that you are wishing them happiness on their belated birthday.

A belated birthday *celebration* is of course perfectly possible, but I'd just say "happy birthday" in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

A "birthdate" is always a specific date. It cannot be delayed like a dentist appointment. Just because you forgot or missed sending your greetings prior to and up to the actual date it has no bearing on the birth date. Your greetings are late or belated. Try to diagram the sentence "I wish you a happy belated birthday."

Answer (score -1):

A ‘Happy Birthday’ would mean- ‘May the day of your birth(current day), happy for you’. So wishing someone delayed, say after 5 days- ‘May your birthday that occurred 5 days ago, should have been happy’ ?? umm.. It does not make any sense. Delayed birthday wishes make no sense other than realizing our mistake. Your feelings are not outdated, anytime you wish, it’s fresh. So I feel, ‘Happy’ should be the first word whenever you wish. The day of birth has gone so ‘belated birthday’ So ‘Happy Belated Birthday.

Comment: As you say, the birthday has gone: the birthday was not belated. It's the wishes that are belated.

Comment: I presume that saying "Happy Birthday" will not actually cause someone to be happy on that day. So whether you say it the day before or a week later, so what? If you insist on a rational interpretation, you could say that you mean "I hope that your just-past birthday was happy" as opposed to "I hope that your upcoming birthday will be happy".

Comment: @Ajay Saying that some phrase usually people say doesn't make sense is out of scope for this forum. This is about English, not about your logic. Anyway, you are taking it too literally; by "happy birthday" people might mean they want the other person feel special, not necessarily happy and certainly not necessarily just on a specific date. Anyway, this does not answer the question.